# multiple IN conditions in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

How can I express the following SQL in JPQL:

```
select * from table where 
( ( table.col1 , table.col2) in 
   (col1val1, col2val1),
   (col1val2, col2val2),
   (col1val3, col2val3)
)
```

BTW: The above is valid Oracle SQL syntax

Answer (score 1):

My JPQL is terrible, but how about something like:

```
select tableDto from TableDto tableDto 
where (tableDto.col1 = col1val1 and tableDto.col2 = col2val1)
or (tableDto.col1 = col1val2 and tableDto.col2 = col2val2)
or (tableDto.col1 = col1val3 and tableDto.col2 = col2val3)
```

It's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Forget what follows, it's not correct. Left in to show thinking**

I think you'd first have to split out the multi-dimensional statement into it's constituents:

```
select * from table 
where table.col1 in (col1val1, col1val2, col1val3)
and table.col2 in (col2val1, col2val2, col2val3)
```

which would translate in JPQL (assuming that "table" is mapped to an entity `TableDto`) like this:

```
select tableDto from TableDto tableDto 
where tableDto.col1 in(col1val1, col1val2, col1val3)
and tableDto.col2 in(col2val1, col2val2, col2val3)
```

The above is untested, but further information can be found in the [JPQL reference documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_in).

Comment: The trouble is that that query will match (col1val1, col2val2), which the original one won't.